# eliminar de una tabla con 2 WHERE sql

Tags: php, sql

Quería saber si existe un equivalente en sql que me permita borrar registros de una tabla cuando en ese registro los valores de dos llaves foráneas coincidan con valores específicos.

Es decir, tengo una tabla estudiantes, la cual tiene 2 llaves foráneas una para "id_curso" al que pertenece
y otra para "id_descuento" al que puede acceder ese estudiante
Quiero hacer algo similar a esto:

"DELETE FROM estudiantes WHERE id_curso=?,  WHERE id_descuento=?"

para no tener que recorrer una lista por php y luego borrar coincidencias.

Comment: Creo que lo que buscas es la clausula `AND`

Comment: busca acerca de las cláusulas `AND` y `OR`, te van a servir mucho para esos casos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM estudiantes WHERE id_curso=? and id_descuento=?
```